Proving that formula is not a tautology
I wonder if there exist a counterexample in topological space semantcis for this formula: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4974561/1262786 . There is an answer using Kripke countermodel, can we rebuild this countermodel into topological space where this formula isn't a tautology?

What sort of topological semantics do you have in mind? There are various different types of topological semantics.

Please edit this question to make it self-contained asap (at the very least, include the formula and a link to the topological semantics for IPC), otherwise it'll definitely be closed.

It is not hard to check that no 3-point topological space suffices to refute this principle. Since the upset topology (as explained in @JoD17's answer below) of the two-chain poset ${W_{11} < W_{12}, W_{21} < W_{22}}$ does, it therefore constitutes a minimal counterexample.

I'm not entirely sure what you have in mind when you say topological space semantics, however there is one version of topological semantics for intuitionistic logic that is quite simple to obtain from the kripke semantics, you just need to consider the upset topology (or Alexandrov topology) of the relevant kripke frame.
First, I will define what I mean by a topological model. Then I will define the upset topology and how to transform a kripke model into a topologal model. Finally, I will point out why the transformed model from the post you linked is a topological model that falsifies the formula $(A\to(B\vee \neg B))\vee (\neg A\to(B\vee \neg B))$.

Before going any further, lets define what I will mean by topological model. For any topological space $(X,\tau)$ we can turn $(X,\tau)$ into a topological model $(X, \tau, V)$ for the language of intuitionistic logic by simply adding valuation $V:Prop\to \tau$ that sends propositional letters to opens sets of the topology i.e for all $p\in Prop$, V(p) is an open set of $(X,\tau)$. We can then extend $V$ to the rest of the language as follows.
$[|p|]_X=V(p)$ for a propositional letter $p$,
$[|\bot|]_X=\emptyset$,
$ [|\phi\wedge \psi|]_X=[|\phi|]_X\cap [|\psi|]_X$,
$ [|\phi\vee\psi|]_X=[|\phi|]_X\cup[|\psi|]_X$,
$[|\phi\to\psi|]_X=int((X-[|\phi|]_X)\cup [|\psi|]_X)$,
In the condition for $\to$ we use the interior operation $int$ which when applied to a subset $Y$ of $X$ returns the greatest open set contained in $Y$.

Now, lets return to what I mean by "upset topology". The upset topology $(P,Up(P))$ of a pre-order $(P,\leq )$ is defined so that the set $Up(P)$ of all upsets of $P$ are the open set of this space. That is, the open sets of $(P,Up(P))$ are the subsets $U$ of $P$ such that if $x\in U$ and $x\leq y$, then $y\in U$.

This gives us a general method for transforming a intuitionistic kripke frame into a topological space since every intuitionistic kripke frame is a pre-order.
Further, for a intuitionistic kripke model $(X,\leq, V)$ (i.e. a frame with a valuation on it), we can always turn it into a topological model $(X,Up(X), V)$ where $(X,Up(X))$ is the upset topology of $(X,\leq)$ and $V$ is the exact same function in both structures. This work because the valuation of an intuitionistic kripke model is already required to be persistent in the sense that whenever a world $w$ satisfies a propositional letter, then all of the worlds above $w$ satisfy that propositional letter too. In other words, for any propositional letter $p$, $V(p)$ is an upset of the preorder $(X,\leq)$.

Finally, using the method outlined above, we can turn the kripke model in the linked post into a topological model. Let $(\{W_0, W_{11}, W_{12}, W_{21}, W_{22}\}, \leq, V)$ be the kripke model from the linked post. So $[|A|]=\{W_{11}, W_{12}\}$ and $[|B|]=\{W_{12}, W_{22}\}$. Then $(\{W_0, W_{11}, W_{12}, W_{21}, W_{22}\},Up(X), V)$, as defined above, is a topological model that makes the formula in question false at the same world as in the linked post.
Basically, what this comes down to showing is that $W_0\not\in [|(A\to(B\vee \neg B))\vee (\neg A\to(B\vee \neg B))|]$. But this is exactly what the post you linked shows.
